# On page refresh index.tsx(loginpage) is loading, even after login is done using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm working on Nextjs project with firebase as backend db. there
are several pages like visitors.tsx, issues.tsx, index.tsx(is my
login page) pages in the nextjs app. After logging in the the app
I'll land on visitors.tsx page. Upto here it's fine. At this
point of time my browser URL is,

```
abc.com----> it will open index.tsx 

abc.com/visitors ---> it will open visitors.tsx page.
```

If i refresh browser it's going to LOGIN page(i.e app.com). any
suggestion on how I can fix this issue?

In my local system it's working fine, not going to login page.
But after deploying in the server. if i refresh then login page is loading(i.e index.tsx)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after long research I fixed this refresh issue in Dev
server.

```
STEP:1(change the next.config.js)

const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
    trailingSlash: true,
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    webpack(config, options) {
      return config
    },
})



 STEP:2
 I think this may not require  if you are not using firebase.
 I changed firebase.json to like below. So, it is not going to index.jsx
   {
     "hosting": {
        "public": "out",
        "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
     }
  }
```